# Installing Latest Ubuntu on old system

Tags: 12.04, installation

Im installing Ubuntu on an old computer that had windows XP on it. It had a corruption in the System 32  file and wouldn't boot up. So I burnt Ubuntu 12.04 LTS to a disc and booted it up. It got as far as Preparing to install Ubuntu, I clicked continue and it's not doing anything. It's not even loading from the disc drive I think.

Comment: What are the hardware specifications?

Comment: Please check your disks. It seems that your disk is broken. Use a live CD from ubuntu and google how to check your disk with a live CD (example http://mikebeach.org/2011/05/21/how-to-check-your-hard-drives-smart-status-using-a-ubuntu-live-cd/ )

Comment: I suggest you also verify that your install media (CD) is OK. (It probably is, but it is also very easy to check so why not do it?) You can verify your CD by running the `Check disc for defects` menu option from the [**Ubuntu CD Advanced Welcome Page**](http://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions#Ubuntu_CD_Advanced_Welcome_Page_Options) of your install CD. To display this menu, press any key after booting your install CD and while the Ubuntu "*small logo*" [*(screenshot)*](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tSYiR.png) is still displayed at the bottom of your screen.

Answer (score 0):

may I suggest 2 things:
(i) did you check the boot sequence in your bios setup
(ii)did you try to run a live usb installation to clear up and then install from it

good luck,
Emmanuel.

Comment: Regarding the boot sequence suggestion: Chris was able to boot from the Ubuntu live CD and get as far as "Preparing to install Ubuntu," so booting the CD is not the problem.